# How to activate WordPress widgets but not display?

Tags: widgets

I have activate the widget in my WordPress site in admin panel, but on the front page I don't want to display it. Is this possible?

Comment: My widget n mega menu yea edit on customised theme can't enable, please guide how to solved issue, My website
dasdeals.in

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a widget that you want to display on every page but the front page? If so, the [Widget Logic plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) will do what you're after. You should be able to use the logic `!is_home()`.

Comment: second that!... Widget Logic multiplies your design possibilities by the hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enable or disable widgets from the Appearance menu of the Wordpress admin panel. Goto Appearance->Widgets then you can drag the widget from the "Sidebar Widgets" area to either the "Available Widgets" or "Inactive Widgets" boxes. If you use the "Inactive Widgets" option, Wordpress will save your widgets settings for later use.